# Postgres - array date column with constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a table `test_table` that has a column `year` which takes an array of 'years', like so:

```
CREATE TABLE avg_yearly_currencies_used (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    year date[],
    CONSTRAINT first_jan_check CHECK ( date_trunc('year', year) = year )
);
```

The `CONSTRAINT` checks to see if the date is in the format such as: `2010-01-01`, or `2012-01-01`.

If the `year` column is not an array, then the above command works fine and the table is created. However, by making the date an array, and by having the `CONSTRAINT`, I get the following error:

`ERROR: function date_trunc(unknown, date[]) does not exist`

How do apply the `CONSTRAINT` to the array column `year`?

Comment: You can maybe do something like this CHECK (year <@ ARRAY[2000,2001,2002...]) that is all i can think of right now

Comment: If you just want to store the years, then why don't you use an integer array? You can easily create a proper date at the first of January from them.

Comment: That is a good point, and I might look into doing that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following approach

1. Write a custom function to check whether all values in the array is complying with the condition:

```
create function check_date (
    date_ date[]) returns boolean as 
    $$
    declare
    result boolean;
    begin
    select bool_and (date_trunc('year', n) = n) into result
    from unnest(date_) s(n);
    return result;
    end;
    $$ 
    language plpgsql immutable;
```

2. Add above function in check constraint

```
CREATE TABLE avg_yearly_currencies_used (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    year date[],
    CONSTRAINT first_jan_check CHECK (check_date(year))
);
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bc3449ef5bdf9017a511668e0df6b4f0)